# Multism simulation for NMOS type circuit, why I am not getting the expected graph?

Tags: circuit-analysis, simulation, nmos, multisim

I am trying to simulate my circuit for one of the question problems. The question looks like this

[image: Picture of the question]

I have written a MATLAB script to see the expected graph

```
%Script for making a plot of the problem 5.26
```

vt = 0.5 ;
vd = 1 ;
k = 2e-3;

vgd = 0:0.1:1.8;
id = zeros(size(vg)); % Initialize id as a vector
i = 1; %just to assign them

for vg = 0:0.1:1.8

```
%cut off situation
if vg <= vt
    id(i) = 0; 
i = i+1; 

%triode situation 
elseif (vd<=(vg-vt))

    id(i) = k.*(vg-vt).*vd - (k.*vd^2/2); 
 i = i+1 ; 
%saturation situation 
elseif (vd>(vg-vt))

    id(i) = k/2.*(vg-vt)^2; 
i = i+1; 
   end

 

end

 plot(vgd, id) ; 

title("Id/Vg relationship graph")
```

Which pretty much give me a graph like this

[image: Expected graph]

I am trying to now simulate it on multisim and I am not getting anything. I am doing DC sweep to analyse the Id. I am changing the vgs with 0.1V increment till 1.8

this is my multisim circuit
[image: simulation]

Comment: The Vd voltage source is not well wired ... And just measure Id vs Vg.

Comment: Thank you. I am getting almost similar but still a little different graph now after counting the vd other part with the ground